# Show a Div, without showing its hidden properties

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, hide, show

Okay so I have a navigation, that is hidden. When you click the trigger, the menu is shown.

I then have sub menus, that are hidden within the container div.

When I click the trigger, everything works fine, but it is showing the sub navigations as well.

Is there anyway to show the menu, on call, without showing the sub navigations?

```
        <div class="sidebardesktop">

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="homenavtoggle">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="prices.html">Prices</a></li>
                        <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="projectnavtoggle">project</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>

                    </ul>

                    <!-- SUB Menu - Desktop Only!
                    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
                    <ul class="home">
                        <li><a href="index.html">HomePage 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="indextwo.html">HomePage 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="indexthree.html">HomePage 3</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="projectnav">
                        <li><a href="project.html">Video Project</a></li>
                        <li><a href="indextwo.html">Big Title Project</a></li>
                        <li><a href="indexthree.html">Gallery Project</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

And the jQuery Below:

```
$('.homenavtoggle').click(function(){
$(".home").show('fastest');});
```

Basically I want to show the .sidebardesktop to show without showing the Sub Menus.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue, it's not clear what you are asking. BTW, what are you expecting using `.show('fastest');`,  `fastest`??? Faster than fast, then set it to 200

Comment: the CSS would help as well.

Comment: Make the submenus have CSS "display: none".

Comment: I have replicated the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/hfhe6/

Comment: I need to do this, without adding inline CSS, i had this in before, but my requirements have to be no inline CSS

Comment: Then you can add CSS class like jmore suggested, still you need to have the CSS rule in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for? you can add a `class` on to the top navigation and target that

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5vy2M/)